# Correct way to access IBM's public FTP

Tags: ftp

Not sure if this is a firewall problem on my end, or if IBM's ftp server is messed up, can someone confirm? 
I'm using SFTP client with passive mode enabled on Windows 7 64bit, Norton Internet Security disabled.

I'm trying to access `software/integration/support/supportpacs`

`ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com`

Tried logging in as `anonymous`, password `hello@foo.com`, keep getting errors from the server saying

> The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was
>   found. Connection failed.

I confirmed it's not a firewall issue by making a test connection to `ftp.ed.ac.uk`

Comment: It works for me. Either your FTP client is broken or your firewall is.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked fine for me (anonymous as username, any password).

I wonder if the problem is that you are using passive mode ?  When I attempted to connect and set passive mode off, the service ground to a halt.

Comment: What client you using?

Comment: I used the simple "FTP" client on my CentOS 5 box.  (I also used NCFTP).

Comment: Making some progress with another client, but no cigar yet :-)

Comment: Maybe you can provide more information, like your OS, the FTP client you are using, if you have tried it from another device not behind a firewall, how long it takes to come up with the error message etc.

Comment: updated with some additional comments, thx